# ContextMenuStrip to appear when rightclick on datagridview via windowsforms host in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, contextmenu, windowsformshost

I have a datagridview created using WindowsFormHost in WPF, code XAML:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Margin="154,63,786,544">
<wf:DataGridView
x:Name="DGV"
Location="0, 0"
ColumnHeadersVisible="True"
SelectionMode="FullRowSelect"   
MultiSelect="False"
SelectionChanged="DataGridViewOnSelectionChanged"
/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

and also a ContextMenuStrip, code XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="CMS">

        <MenuItem Header="CMS">
            <MenuItem Header="1" Click="one">               
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem Header="2" Click="two">                
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem Header="3" Click="three">               
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem Header="4" Click="four">
            </MenuItem>

        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
```

And I want to show the ContextMenuStrip when "rightclicking" on the datagridview so I wrote this:

```
Public Sub ClickMouse(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellMouseClick

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        CMS.Show(Windows.Forms.DataGridView.MousePosition)
        MsgBox("WTF")
    End If

End Sub
```

But when I rightclick on the DataGridView "DGV", the ContextMenuStrip "CMS" does not appears? What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The Show function expects the Point passed to it to be in screen coordinates.